# RealmObject relationships on deletion

Tags: realm

quick question concerning Realm objects and their relationships.

Let's say, I have author1 with field Realmlist, having added book1 and book2 to that list.
Creating one transaction to add author1 to realm will automatically add book1 and book2 to the database as I noticed. author1 has a reference to the books, but the books do not have a reference to their author.

My question is, what happens if I delete author1 from realm? What will happen to book1 and book2? Should I first call getBookList() and delete them or will they be automatically deleted from my database?

Comment: I can tell you that creating this in code could take… 10 minutes? Have you tried it? :) (hint: the books won't be automatically deleted)

Comment: cascading deletes are not supported yet, see issue https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1104

Comment: how to overcome this restriction.
Imagine a database of 3000 authors, each having 3 books, that's 9000 books, AND authors are constantly being added/deleted, so books keep piling up in the database with no way of deleting them?

My solution was to add a reference to the author too in the book, then do a search once for the books by the author and delete, then another search for the author to be deleted and delete him. Is that the best approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as beeender mentioned the cascading deletes are still an issue.
My solution is to link each book to the author, do a fori instead of a foreach loop and delete the books one by one before deleting the main author.

Still open to other answers though.

Comment: Nah, that's the way to do it